# Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)

Tags: boot, usb, 15.10, .desktop

I've created a 15.10 Ubuntu USB drive and booting off it with an ASUS Rampage IV Black Edition motherboard, I get:

`Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)`

and then nothing. I've become really frustrated trying to get a stable BIOS config with this motherboard (every boot produces an Overclocking failed! message and none of the even low-key default options avoid this message with an i7 3930K - this board rules as the hardest motherboard I have ever configured in the last 10 years!) and now it can't boot a vanilla 15.10 USB drive. I'd really value some help..

**EDIT**

I found the solution. See below.

Comment: That's not a fatal message, ignore it.  You seem to have a video problem, what graphics chip/card are you using?

Comment: An Nvidia GTX400 card. It was working fine before the motherboard swap I've done.

Comment: try to boot with kernel paramenter `nomodeset`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to waiting,  add the boot parameter `nomodeset` to grub during boot. This can be done by pressing `e` on the grub menu entry and then inserting `nomodeset` on the Linux line.

This seems to be a problem caused by the most recent kernel and Nouveau, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this, somewhat unexpectedly. The answer is **wait 10 minutes**.

My research had indicated that the message itself is not the problem. What is occurring is that the next part of the bootup process is completely silent when a problem occurs. I suspected it was video card related and tried some different cards but unfortunately they were all Nvidia cards and none of them had any impact on the problem.

As it happened, I was looking at different kernel possibilities than that in the standard desktop install USB (on my Mac) and I looked over to the Ubuntu install to amazingly see *the initial install screen with it's choices*.

Whatever is happening, it takes about 10 minutes for that step to timeout. After which the install will progress as expected!

Comment: hello , to me , i still have that problem , waiting till now like ...1hrs...